# Number of elements with a certain property in $S_5$: what does $S_5$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am working on the following problem:

> Determine number of elements in $\{
> \rho \in S_5\vdots \ \rho (2)=5
> \}$

I have difficulty to understand what is asked for. Specifically:

- Is $S_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?
- What does $\rho (2)=5$ mean?

Comment: No, $S_5$ is not the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, rather $S_5$ is the symmetric group containing all permutations (bijective functions) of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. So $\rho$ is a function, and $\rho(2)=5$ says when you plug $2$ into $\rho$ as input you get $5$ as its output. That's function notation, which ought to be taught well before group theory.

Comment: $S_{5}$ is a group (the symmetric group of degree 5). I could be misunderstanding, but if you don't know what $S_{5}$ means, then were did you encounter this question?

Comment: I see now that i tackled this all wrong. I've now read more about symmetric groups. Thanks!

Comment: To get braces { } in math mode, just use \{ and \}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\rho$ is a permutation. After fixing $\rho(2)=5$ there are $4!$ ways to assign the results of applying $\rho$ to $1,3,4,5$, so the answer is $24$.

Answer (score 2):

Hi hope you're having a jolly christmas!

$p$ is just a function of the form(just an example)$f(x)=(2,5)(1,3,4)$ were $f(2)=5$ and $f(3)=1$, $f(4)=1$. And $g(x)=(1,2,3,4,5)$ with $g(2)=3$ is another example. It's the permutation of $S_5$.(Sorry my English is really bad)